# Create a vector of distinct months associated to my ids

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I'm new to R and i know a bit of `dplyr` now. I need to associate to every Id in my dataframe the distinct months observed (column YM). I'm pretty stuck on it because i don't even really know where to put it when I've correctly associated the months to the ids, maybe a list i can access through my Ids? 
For the association id-month I thought about the `spread` function of `tidyr` but i can't make that work. Here an example of dataset:

```
Id     YM
103285   201401  
103285   201402  
103285   201410  
103285   201411  
103285   201412  
103285   201501  
103285   201502  
103346   201408  
103346   201409  
103346   201410  
103346   201411  
103346   201412  
103346   201501  
103346   201502
```

Expected Result:

```
103285 c(01, 02, 10, 11, 12)  
103346 c(08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02)
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use `split` to break up the YM variables by ID, and then run through the result list with `lapply`. `substring` pulls the substring of the final two characters in ym and `unique` drops repeating values. This returns a named list where the name of each list item is the ID.

```
lapply(split(dat$YM, dat$Id), function(x) unique(substring(x, nchar(x)-1L)))
$`103285`
[1] "01" "02" "10" "11" "12"

$`103346`
[1] "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "01" "02"
```

If we know that the values in YM will always be 6 characters, we could replace `substring(x, nchar(x)-1L)` with `substring(x, 5)` or `substring(x, 5, 6)`. The returned values are character, which preserves the leading 0.

An alternative if you don't mind losing the leading 0s would be to use the modulus operator.

```
lapply(split(dat$YM, dat$Id), function(x) unique(x %% 100))
$`103285`
[1]  1  2 10 11 12

$`103346`
[1]  8  9 10 11 12  1  2
```

If maintaining the leading 0s is important, you can add them back with `sprintf`

```
lapply(split(dat$YM, dat$Id), function(x) sprintf("%02.0f", unique(x %% 100)))
$`103285`
[1] "01" "02" "10" "11" "12"

$`103346`
[1] "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "01" "02"
```

Comment: Thanks lmo, for the sake of learning what could be another alternative?

Comment: @fedezi I've added a third option that prepends leading 0s if that is needed after using the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think base R is better suited here, but a possible solution with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Id) %>% 
summarize(months = list(unique(substr(YM,5,6)))) %>% 
as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
      Id                     months
1 103285         01, 02, 10, 11, 12
2 103346 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02
```

Note that the months are now in lists, so to get a vector of the months corresponding to 103285, you have to do:

```
x$months[x$Id==103285][[1]]
```

whereas with lmo's solution you could simply do

```
x['103285']
```

to find the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

with `tidyR` and the `nest` function you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyR)
df1 %>% mutate(YM =substr(YM,5,6)) %>% unique %>% nest(YM,.key=YM) %>% as.data.frame
      Id                         YM
1 103285         01, 02, 10, 11, 12
2 103346 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(YM~Id, df, function(x)
    unique(substr(x, nchar(x)-1, nchar(x))), simplify = FALSE)
#      Id                         YM
#1 103285         01, 02, 10, 11, 12
#2 103346 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02
```

OR

```
aggregate(YM~Id, df, function(x){
    unique(format(as.Date(paste0(x, 01), format = "%Y%m%d"), "%m"))
}, simplify = FALSE)
#      Id                         YM
#1 103285         01, 02, 10, 11, 12
#2 103346 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 01, 02
```